# Unable to update user full name on Soundcloud, over api access?

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

Are anyone using Soundcloud.com api and trying to update user[full_name] ?!

I'm developing my own PHP wrapper, but I've tested with the 'Official supported' php wrapper, with no luck too.

Is it possible that 'full_name' is a read-only data field?!

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with access token
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
// get authrization login
// authorize application, get the CODE here
// ...
// then set the oauth2_token to access 'private' aka logged-in-only resources
$client->setAccessToken('ACCESS_TOKEN');

// get the current user
$user = json_decode($client->get('me'));

// update the user's profile full_name
$user = json_decode($client->put('me', array(
'user[full_name]' => 'John Doe'
)));
print $user->full_name;
```

When i run this code.. I receive on my cURL handler a HTTP CODE of 200 OK.
but the full name is never updated on soundcloud. I can with the same code update 'description', or 'city' fields.

it's possible that 'full_name' is a read-only?!

Soundcloud documentation is very 'limited' (on lack of better word, english is not my native language) and I can't find there (developers.soundcloud.com) any information regarding 'non-updatable' data fields.

Thanks for your help in advance,
and Sorry for my bad English.